# I can't access my Magento Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, frontend, shopping-cart

I change my admin URL to a custom URL and I cannot access my store admin anymore.

How can I revert the change that I made?

Comment: Detail the process of changing it in the first place. What did you do?

Comment: change in app/etc/env.php file

Answer (score 1):

**Cache**

If you did not flush the cache after the changed URL, flush it with:

`bin/magento cache:flush`

**Show Admin URL info**

You can find out about the current admin url via:

`bin/magento info:adminuri`

**app/etc/env.php**

You can also view the admin url in app/etc/env.php:

```
  'backend' =>
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin_1wgrah',
  ),
```

Comment: thanks for your help Anna, I have never used the code before, I merely use the admin panel to add products to the store front, create some pages, add needed links, etc.